# Backbone view don't get el in template

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

i'm calling a view of list element with itself html ,in this view there is an iterative calling to another view of single item.The proble is that the first view of listelement can't see itself html. If i set el to get id (el:$("#pagination-centered") ) ,where i want append the iterative single element,don't render.

View of listelement:

```
        define(["jquery", "underscore", "Backbone", "Handlebars",  
   "views/singlepostview", "text!templates/home.html"],**<--html**
   function ($, _, Backbone, Handlebars,SinglePost, template) {

  var Home = Backbone.View.extend({
   el:$("#pagination-centered"),//it is inside home.html defined above 

    template: Handlebars.compile(template),

    initialize: function () {
     // this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);

    },


       events: {

    },      



    render: function (eventName) {
       $(this.el).empty();
      _.each(this.model.models, function (ad) {
        $(this.el).append(new SinglePost({
          model: ad
        }).render().el);
      }, this);


      return this;



         }




         });

     return Home;

      });
```

view of singleelement:

```
        define(["jquery", "underscore", "Backbone", "Handlebars", "text!templates/singlepost.html"],
function ($, _, Backbone, Handlebars, template) {

var SinglePost = Backbone.View.extend({
     //el:$("#pagination-centered"),
    //tagName: "li",

    events: {
      "click": "goToDetails"
    },

    template: Handlebars.compile(template),

    initialize: function () {
      this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
      this.model.bind("destroy", this.close, this);
    },

    render: function (eventName) {
      var ad = this.model.toJSON();
     // console.log(ad);
      ad.cid = this.model.cid;
      $(this.el).html(this.template(ad));
      return this;
    },

    goToDetails: function () {
      Backbone.history.navigate("#user/"+this.model.id, {trigger: true});
    }
  });

return SinglePost;
```

Template associated to view Home(list of element):

```
         <div class="row">

            <div class="page-header ">
              <p class="pull-right"><a href="#">see all</a></p>
              <h4>Honors <small>(10)</small></h4>
            </div>

            <div class="pagination-centered">


            </div>

       </div>
```

Template associated to view SinglePost(item of list):

```
       <a href="#"><img src="{{immagine.url}}" class="img-circle"></a>
```

I want render this (last) singlepost template of singlepost view inside template of Home view and specifically inside div class="pagination-centered".
Will be done as:

```
              **<div class="row">

            <div class="page-header ">
              <p class="pull-right"><a href="#">see all</a></p>
              <h4>Honors <small>(10)</small></h4>
            </div>

            <div class="pagination-centered">

            *<a href="#"><img src="{{immagine.url}}" class="img-circle"></a>*


            </div>
          </div>**
```

Comment: Logic problem here, your element shouldn't be in the view's template. Why don't you create it with your view? Use the `tagName` and `attributes` attributes.

Comment: Because i need insert the result of iterative views of single element in a complex html like this: <div class="row">
              
                <div class="page-header ">
                  <p class="pull-right"><a href="#">see all</a></p>
                  <h4>Honors <small>(10)</small></h4>
                </div>
               
                <div class="pagination-centered">
                    
                    
                </div>
    
    </div>

Comment: how can i create a complex html with tagname and attributes?

Comment: Well, use `tagName`, `id` and `attributes` as the parameters of your element, and when you instantiate your view, your element will be created. You simply have to append it to the DOM. And btw, if the html you need to input isn't just just the `#pagination-centered` element, it should not be appended with the view.

Comment: So i can create a complex html like above simply using tagName?

Answer (score 1):

`$("#pagination-centered")` will look for that selector in the current window dom. This means that if the content of your template (where the `pagination-centered` element is defined) is not in the dom, it won't be find (yelding to a null `el` and nothing being rendered).

I think there are clearer way to achieve good templating in Backbone, but what would be quick and easy in your case is to create the views as

```
var Home = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "section",
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html( /* load the content of your home template here */);
        var list = this.$('#pagination-centered')
        for ( ... ) // here you loop over your models
            list.append(singlePost.render().el);
        return this;
}

var SinglePost = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html( /* load the content of your single post template here */);
        return this;
    }
}
```

One of the common pitfalls in Backbone Views is that each view has an *implicit* element that wraps everything that gets rendered. In this case for example your Home template will be rendered within a `section`. What you tried to do (assigning the `el` property to a certain dom selector) while tecnically possible, is not the common or suggested way to achieve that.

Another suggestion is to try to have meaningful and semantically correct markup. If `pagination-centered` is a list, it should be a `ul` or `ol`, not a `div`.

Comment: i need to catch $("#pagination-centered") from PostList template,because in this template there are several nested html that i need and can't do it by onli tag name. May I create a second function render in postlist view to render and attach  to dom the itself template and after catch it in the first function render to append the iterative view?

Comment: I guess it would be better if you edit your question and add the template you are talking about (so we can see the actual markup and understand better what you want to achieve). I think I've got your problem but not being 100% sure I'd like to see the markup.

Comment: Ok, yes I see the template, and that is what I thought so what I wrote in my answer still applies. I will edit my answer and add details on how to do that.